# Инициализация массива на базе значений другого

Tags: c++, массивы

Привожу сразу код для прояснения:

```
struct S {
    S(int) {}
};

int iArr[] = { 1, 2, 3 }; 
S sArr[] = { iArr[0], iArr[1], iArr[2] };
```

Хочется избежать ручного изменения кода инициализации массива `sArr` при изменении количества значений в `iArr`. Интересует именно *compile-time* инициализация.

Возможно ли это? Если да, то как?

Интересуют варианты как для с++03 (наверное без макросов тут не обойтись), так и современный подход (скорее всего *variadic-templates*). Если что-то подходящее ожидается в новом Стандарте, то тоже было бы неплохо увидеть в ответах.

Comment: [вот это не поможет](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108390/c11-compile-time-calculation-of-array)?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, но набор тегов весьма необычный :)

Comment: А зачем к общему тегу языка теги всех версий? Мы ж вроде [условились, что общая метка языка относится ко **всем** версиям](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/a/3828/181100)? Или вы хотели исключить C++98? :D Или он просто в метки не влез?

Comment: @D-side я почему-то был уверен, что при голой метке будет подразумеваться **последняя** доступная версия. Уберу излишки тогда.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

C++14 [решение](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/UEFKlTvDMJ5Y20Z0) на базе [кода](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/33688255#33688255) @Abyx:

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

struct S 
{
    constexpr S(int i) : i(i*i) { }
    int i;
};

template<typename R, typename S, size_t... I>
constexpr auto makeArrayHelper(const S(&src)[sizeof...(I)], std::index_sequence<I...> ) 
{
    return std::array<R, sizeof... (I)>{ { src[I]... } };
}

template<typename R, typename S, size_t N>
constexpr auto makeArray(const S(&src)[N]) 
{
    return makeArrayHelper<R>(src, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

int main() 
{
    constexpr int iArr[] = { 1, 2, 3 };     

    constexpr auto sArr = makeArray<S>(iArr);

    for( auto& s : sArr )
    {
        std::cout << s.i << "\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Гм, для C++03 через `#define` - чем не вариант

```
#define  INIT { 1, 6, 3, 7, 8, 9 }

int iArr[] = INIT;
S sArr[] = INIT;
```

? :)

Comment: http://codepad.org/LHkKucFt - ой.. опоздал я с ответом на <s>18</s> 9 минут...

Comment: `constexpr` для с++03? :) А так, конечно, хорошо. Проще пареной репы получилось.

Comment: @alexolut Да нет, sorry, это у меня осталось от экспериментов...

Comment: Выгляит не очень compile-time'ово (без constexpr)

Comment: @AndreyBuran, да не, вполне себе. Это ж define, а присваивания массивов не существует.

Comment: Ооооп! https://godbolt.org/g/YjkrRX - обратите внимание на код функции main

Comment: @AndreyBuran только не на `main`, а на `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0`. Вызов конструкторов `S` будет в runtime, да.

Comment: @AndreyBuran А вот если `struct S { S(int i):j(i){}; int j; };` - то VC++2015 честно выполнит инициализацию во время компиляции. А если, скажем, `S(int i){ cout << i; }` - то это никакой компилятор на уровне компиляции не сделает.

Comment: @Harry ну потому что нарушает правила для выполнения `constexpr` в compile-time